# how to create an map object of type array of structs

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct
{
int    m_x[5];
int    m_y[5];
} my_struct;
```

I would like to create a map object of type my_struct.

```
 std::map<int, my_struct> map_object;
```

In the for loop I want to initialize the values to member of my struct. how do I do it and if I want to do this in a function and return the map_object what would I return back?

Comment: Off topic: `typedef struct { blah blah blah } my_struct;` The `typedef` is unnecessary noise in C++. `struct my_struct { blah blah blah };` can be used as `my_struct` without any further effort and makes life easier for any indexing your IDE performs for you. This syntax is a bit of a red flag. Often it means the writer knows C programming, not C++, and you might have to double check some of their other suggestions.

Comment: On topic, are the map initialization values known at compilation time?

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how you can fill up your map with your struct in a for-loop. It also shows how you can then access a struct member.

```
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct my_struct
{
    std::array<int, 5> m_x;
    std::array<int, 5> m_y;

    my_struct(std::array<int, 5> x, std::array<int, 5> y) : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {}
};


int main()
{
    std::map<int, my_struct> myMap;

    // Adding elements to the map using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::array<int, 5> x = { i,i,i,i,i };
        std::array<int, 5> y = { 0,0,0,i,i };
        myMap.insert(std::pair<int, my_struct>(i, my_struct(x,y)));
    }

    // accessing m_x
    std::cout << "Member with key 1 has m_x[0] value of: " 
              << myMap.at(1).m_x[0] << std::endl;
}
```

To have a function return a map you simply return the map as in modern C++ the compiler should remove the need for deep copy.

```
std::map<int, my_struct> getAMap()
{
    std::map<int, my_struct> myMap;

    // Adding elements to the map using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    // ...

    return myMap;
}

int main()
{
    auto myMap = getAMap();

    // accessing m_x
    std::cout << "Member with key 1 has m_x[0] value of: " 
              << myMap.at(1).m_x[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
std::map<int, my_struct>::iterator it = map_object.begin();
while (it != map_object.end()){
    my_struct& struct_to_intialize = it->second;
    //do things with struct_to_initialize
    it++;
}
```

But instead, if you include a constructor for your struct, like:

```
my_struct::my_struct(){
    //initialize as you please
}
```

then everything can be done implicitly.

Note: typedef is not needed in C++, you should declare your struct as

```
struct my_struct {
    int m_x[5];
    int m_y[5];
};
```

Comment: Straubnger if I would like to initialise map_object struct members with an array which holds the values, how is it done? and how can i access the struct member for ex. m_x[3]?

Comment: @VinayBalajiRajputh using the struct_to_intialize pointer to access each struct member in the map, sequentially.

Comment: `my_struct* struct_to_intialize = *it;` will never compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, I was confusing myself with std::set iterators